# Glassfish 4 fresh download won't work

Tags: password, glassfish

I downloaded a fresh glassfish4 ZIP, decompressed it and ran it. However, I cannot access the admin console on localhost:4848, it keeps redirecting to index.jsf from unknown, and the server log keeps showing the certificate expired related messages.

Admin default user does not have a password, and change-admin-password says wrong user or password.

It's been like that for the past 10 minutes, and it definitely won't work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the admin default password is nothing, so I changed it through asadmin change-admin-password and the redirections stopped.